# Why using find_if like this fail?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, find, stl-algorithm

I want to find the first nonzero element from a map, therefore I did the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

bool nonzero(std::map<char,int>::const_iterator& it);

int main()  {
    std::map<char, int> m;
    m['a'] = 0;
    m['b'] = 1;
    std::map<char,int>::iterator it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), nonzero);
    std::cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


bool nonzero(std::map<char,int>::const_iterator& it)    {
    return it->second;
}
```

The g++ give errors that is very complicated, saying that:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:234:30: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const char, int> >&’ from expression of type ‘std::pair<const char, int>’
  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
```

I don't understand what does it saying and why my program will fail.

Comment: `find_if` passes `*i` to your function, not `i`.

Comment: Double check the predicate requirements [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: Look up *any* example of using `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type expected for your `nonzero` function called by `find_if` is *not* a `std::map<char,int>::const_iterator&`, but a `const std::pair<const char, int> &`.

In fact, if you check some [online documentation for `find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), you'll see that the unary predicate has the form:

> ```
> bool UnaryPredicate(const Type&)
> ```

where `Type` is in your case `std::pair<const char, int>` (for a general `std::map<Key, Value>`, the type is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`).

So you may adjust your function passing a `const&` to that `std::pair`:

```
bool nonzero(const std::pair<const char, int> & p)
{
    return (p.second != 0);
}
```

Note that using C++14 `auto` with lambdas would have simplified your code, e.g.:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const auto& p){
    return (p.second != 0);
});
```

Note also that the pair is of the general form `std::pair<const Key, Value>` (not just `pair<Key, Value>` with non-const Key).

Answer (score 4):

`find_if` passes `value_type` (actually, `iterator.operator*()`) to the function/function object passed to it. Your `nonzero` should accept `std::map<char,int>::value_type const&` as a parameter, or, more succintly: `std::pair<const char, int> const&`

```
bool nonzero(std::pair<const char, int> const& element) {
    return it.second;
}
```

Note that the pair's key is `const`. if you omit it, you'll be copying every map element you check.

If you can use C++14 or newer, you could also make it even shorter with `auto` and a generic lambda:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](auto const& pair){ return p.second; });
```

And C++11 version:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [](std::pair<const char, int> const& pair){ return p.second; })
```

Comment: Note, lambda's Are C++11 or higher only.

Answer (score 2):

Function accepts:

```
bool nonzero(const std::map<char,int>::value_type& value);
```

which is `std::pair<const char,int>`, not iterator

You should check result of `find_if` by comparing with `std::map::end()` before using that iterator.